# Is it possible to create screen saver app for Apple iWatch

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode6

Am new to Apple iWatch app development. is that possible to create screen saver app for Apple iwatch. Plz help me.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not. The Apple Watch will deactivate itself after a few minutes or switch of when it's turned away from its owner. Then it automatically returns to the main Watch Face. A screen saver app would therefore not work, as it would constantly be disabled. It also wouldn't be smart to have one, as this is unnecessary.

Hope that helps,

Julian